# How to check if NSString has a URL with a specific address

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I've been searching and trying different things, but come up short handed.

I am trying to take a URL that someone has copied i.e.: https://website/u/drksndrs and compare it with an if statement basically saying if copied string matches https://website/u/ prefix then go ahead with the program. Searching for different users based on their ID after u/. Here is the code I have right now.

```
NSString *latest = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
NSString *prefix = @"https://www.website.com/u/";
NSRange textRange = [latest rangeOfString:prefix];
if (textRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"the prefix matches!");
    [self performOperation];
} else {
    NSLog(@"This doesn't match the https://www.website.com/u/ prefix.");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be checking if `textRange.location == 0` to see if it is a prefix. Better yet, use the `hasPrefix:` method.

```
NSString *latest = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
NSString *prefix = @"https://www.website.com/u/";
if ([latest hasPrefix:prefix]) {
    NSLog(@"the prefix matches!");
    [self performOperation];
} else {
    NSLog(@"This doesn't match the https://www.website.com/u/ prefix.");
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Something so simple, how did I forget about this method. Thank you!